# Android Development: Transfer App wireless

Tags: android

is it somehow possible to transfer and launch an app I am developing wireless? For example via wifi or bluetooth.

I am developing with android studio (beta) 0.8.9.

Comment: Couldn't you just take the .apk file and send it via one of these methods?

Comment: There are some solutions like adb over TCP/IP. You could google after that. Cyanogenmod has it implemented in its ROM. So you could debug over wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to extract your .apk file. You can do it by right clicking on your project directory and then,

***Android Tools > Export Unsigned Application Package***

Then send it the way you want.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this, please explain I am wondering.